# TLJH behind NGINX, make proxy Traefik listen to port on localhost only

Tags: nginx, traefik, jupyterhub

I want to put TLJH behind NGIX, I succeeded in that by putting the Traefik port in TLJH on 8080 using `sudo tljh-config set to port 8080` and having NGINX doing the SSL part and reverse proxying to port 8080.

Only I can still access TLJH without SSL by :8080 which I want to prevent.

I need to set the Traefik listening port to `127.0.0.1:8080` instead of `*:8080`.
The traefik.toml cannot be changed directly as it is overwritten, `tljh-config` should be used.
Only `tljh-config` does not seem to offer me the possibility of setting the address, only the port.

Adding a python file into the `jupyterhub_config.d` folder with `c.JupyterHub.bind_url = 'http://127.0.0.1'` did not do anything (checking traefik.toml after reloading hub and proxy)

Any idea how to make TLJH's Traefik listen to local port 8080 only?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `.toml` config file for Traefik in `/opt/tljh/config/traefik_config.d` with the following content:

   ```
   [entryPoints]
     [entryPoints.http]
     address = "127.0.0.1:8080"
   ```
2. Reload Traefik config: `sudo tljh-config reload proxy`
3. Restart Traefik and JupyterHub:

   1. `sudo systemctl stop traefik`
   2. `sudo systemctl restart jupyterhub` (starts Traefik automatically)

Traefik should now listen on 127.0.0.1:8080.

---

Sources:

- https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/topic/escape-hatch.html#extending-traefik-toml
- https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/entrypoints/